# Special function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

[image]

Hi everyone, please advise.

I can't come up with a combination of functions (MATCH,LOOKUP,etc.) in Google Sheets that would return the row number of the cell that matches the given rule in the given range. Moreover, I need to find this value from bottom to top.

I am attaching an image in which I show the invented function "FIRST_VALUE", which in this particular case should return the value "5", because just 5 rows above is the value 655.79, which is higher than the rule ">655".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ROW()-INDEX(MAX(IF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW())>655; ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW())); )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find the first value which match the criteria from the point where the formula is written, try

```
=query(arrayformula(sort({offset($A$1,,,row()),row(offset($A$1,,,row()))},2,0)),"select Col1 where Col1>655 order by Col2 desc limit 1")
```

To get both the value and the number of rows, try

```
=query(arrayformula(sort({offset($A$1,,,row()),row(offset($A$1,,,row()))},2,0)),"select Col1, "&row()&"-Col2 where Col1>655 order by Col2 desc limit 1 label "&row()&"-Col2 '' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler option:

```
=ArrayFormula(ROW()-MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A>655)*(ROW(A:A)<ROW())))
```

[image]